# How to handle the EndSave event (AutoCAD .net vb)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, autocad

How to handle the EndSave event (.net vb)?

I don't understand this:

[AutoCAD Dev's guide](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer's%20Guide/index.html?url=WS1a919382)

Also I don't get it if it is a DocumentEvent or DocumentCollectionEvent.

Like what is the correct name of the event? I can't find it. And what name should the procedure have?

Here is my code for an AutoCAD plugin which already registers when the user closes AutoCAD. I want it to register the EndSave as well, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

```
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.IO



Public Class Class1


<CommandMethod("AddAppEvent")>
Public Sub AddAppEvent()
AddHandler Application.DocumentManager.DocumentActivated, AddressOf AcadDocument_EndSave
AddHandler Application.SystemVariableChanged, AddressOf appSysVarChanged 'adicionado para o save
End Sub



<CommandMethod("RemoveAppEvent")>
Public Sub RemoveAppEvent()
RemoveHandler Application.SystemVariableChanged, AddressOf appSysVarChanged
End Sub



Public Sub AcadDocument_EndSave(ByVal DocumentCollection As Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices. 
DocumentCollectionEventArgs)



Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\rita.aguiar\Documents\AutoCAD plug-in\Registo de Eventos.txt", True)
file.WriteLine("O documento foi guardado.")
file.Close()

End Sub



Public Sub appSysVarChanged(ByVal senderObj As Object,
ByVal sysVarChEvtArgs As Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.
SystemVariableChangedEventArgs)

Dim oVal As Object = Application.GetSystemVariable(sysVarChEvtArgs.Name)

Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\rita.aguiar\Documents\AutoCAD plug-in\Registo de Eventos.txt", True)
file.WriteLine("O AutoCAD foi encerrado.")
file.Close()

End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you [AutoCAD event handler](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/handling-events-in-vbnet.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no EndSave Event.
I decided to use the EndCommand Event instead and register when the user finishes the SAVE, SAVEAS and QSAVE commands.